# Angular pass data in the route

Tags: angular, typescript

I am passing data this way

```
console.log(this.regForm.value); //there is data
    this._router.navigate(["/tsafety/checklist-checks"], this.regForm.value);
```

In the component with routing `checklist-checks` am trying to retrieve the data using

```
constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute)
{
  this.route
   .params
    .subscribe(params => {
      this.truckdetails = params; //this is never set
      console.log(params);// this is empty
     });
}
```

Whenever I am trying to accessing `this.truckdetails` it is always empty.

What else do I need to add to get the passed data?

Answer (score 1):

You should try accessing data using `this.route.snapshot.data['yourdata']`

Answer (score 1):

The navigation is incorrect. Optional params (like the form data that you are passing) should reside inside the square brackets. The second argument of the navigate() function takes extra information regarding the navigation. See : https://angular.io/api/router/Router#navigate

Your code should be

```
this._router.navigate(["/tsafety/checklist-checks", this.regForm.value]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I use switchMap in my project.

```
this.route.params
  .switchMap((params: Params) => {
   console.log(params);
});
```